# To which age these coins belong?

Tags: identification, numismatics

I want to know where and in what age these 2 coins were produced:[image]

[image]

Comment: Where did you find them? What country?

Comment: They seem quite similar to coins being marketed as [medieval Indian coins on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Medieval-Indian-Rajputs-Mahipala-JITAL/dp/B07DZJS938),, but not quite the same.

Comment: If you google "medieval coin [...]", and fill the blank with Persia, India, Malaysia, or Sumatra, you'll find plenty of similar coinage with the same style from those areas. It was likely minted by a muslim state in South or Central Asia.